# How to get input in tcell

Tags: go

I want to get input in tcell. I'm writing a text editor, and I want to have a command-prompt, like vim. I'm tried use fmt package, but fmt.Scan and fmt.Scanf are not working (In my case).

Edit:

Ok now I have input, but how I can use it with if? I know about convert rune in graphic, but this is not working with if. Any ideas?

```
func (cmd *Cmd) HandleEvent(event tcell.Event) {
    e.screen.Clear()

    for{
        e.screen.Show()

        event := e.screen.PollEvent()
        style := tcell.StyleDefault.Foreground(tcell.ColorWhite).Background(tcell.ColorBlack)

        switch event := event.(type) {
            case *tcell.EventKey:
                r := event.Rune()

                e.screen.SetContent(8, 40, r, nil, style)       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post a code snippet of what you've done and where you're stuck so that you can be assisted

Answer (score 0):

The `mouse.go` demo from tcell might be most useful for you: https://github.com/gdamore/tcell/blob/master/_demos/mouse.go

tcell appears to use events to record keyboard and mouse input, e.g. here `s.SetContent()` is used to display `ev.Rune()` which is the key that has been pressed... from the demo for mouse/keyboard input:

```
        case *tcell.EventKey:
            s.SetContent(w-2, h-2, ev.Rune(), nil, st)
            s.SetContent(w-1, h-1, 'K', nil, st)
            if ev.Key() == tcell.KeyEscape {
                ecnt++
                if ecnt > 1 {
                    s.Fini()
                    os.Exit(0)
                }
            } else if ev.Key() == tcell.KeyCtrlL {
                s.Sync()
            } else {
                ecnt = 0
                if ev.Rune() == 'C' || ev.Rune() == 'c' {
                    s.Clear()
                }
            }
            lks = ev.Name()
```

https://github.com/gdamore/tcell/blob/master/_demos/mouse.go#L161